# React Native linker command failed with exit code 1 with default app

Tags: ios, reactjs, native

I used React Native a few years back and am starting up using it again so I was just testing with the default app to check it builds ok in iOS. It runs ok in the simulator in xcode after opening the `xcworkspace` file but when selecting to build for release it fails with the classic linker error.

I noticed 'main.jsbundle' is red and thus missing from the project which I used to need to create but not sure if we still need to or how it is done? I checked the official documentation and there is a section for submitting to the play store...but no section about submitting to the Apple App store?? Can we not submit to the Apple store anymore?

The versions are:

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.4",
```

I looked around for guides on submitting to the iOS store written by third parties but they are either a 1-2 years old or more or don't mention anything I haven't done. Again, no idea why there is no official documentation on iOS submission, unless it is harder to find than the Android one.

Error message in full:

```
Ld /Users/hasen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-eeaxrfrnodznmfdedeoxgnyekkae/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app.build/Release-iphoneos/appTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/appTests normal arm64 (in target: appTests)
    cd /Volumes/Orchestra/Projects/reactnative/app/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk -L/Users/hasen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-eeaxrfrnodznmfdedeoxgnyekkae/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/hasen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-eeaxrfrnodznmfdedeoxgnyekkae/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/hasen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-eeaxrfrnodznmfdedeoxgnyekkae/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app.build/Release-iphoneos/appTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/appTests.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -bundle_loader /Users/hasen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-eeaxrfrnodznmfdedeoxgnyekkae/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/app.app/app -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/hasen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-eeaxrfrnodznmfdedeoxgnyekkae/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app.build/Release-iphoneos/appTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/appTests_lto.o -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lc++ -lstdc++ -framework JavaScriptCore -framework XCTest -lPods-appTests -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/hasen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-eeaxrfrnodznmfdedeoxgnyekkae/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app.build/Release-iphoneos/appTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/appTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/hasen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-eeaxrfrnodznmfdedeoxgnyekkae/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app.build/Release-iphoneos/appTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/appTests

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_RCTSetLogFunction", referenced from:
      -[appTests testRendersWelcomeScreen] in appTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: try to run 

react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios

in your code and restart xcode and check if main.jsbundle color changed or not

Comment: @Saloni Parikh Is this what we're supposed to do? Can you point me to the official documentation on this. I really couldn't find anything about this main.jsbundle and what to do with it.

Comment: @Saloni Parikh That did create the main.jsbundle file ok, but it still fails to build with the same error. Really not sure why there's no documentation on all this...

Comment: can you show me the error you've get.

Comment: @Saloni Parikh It's in my question.

Comment: ya,I know its written in your question. but i didn't get what you do you mean by classic linker error
so it would be nice if you share whole error

Comment: @Saloni Parikh No the error is in the title.

Comment: before this error you got something written, maybe that was the error.

or try to remove **derived data ** and restart xcode may help

Comment: Not sure what you mean by remove `derived data`. Is there no guide or documentation? Is iOS no longer supported for React Native? So strange...

Comment: I don't no about docs but what i know i can tell you.
you can refer https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22093
can try 
react-native link

Comment: @Saloni Parikh Ok I found how to remove derived data, did that and restarted Xcode but it still throws the same error.

Comment: @Saloni Parikh Yes I already saw that. I tried everything in there like `react native link` in the project folder and also deleting and reinstalling the node modules. Every time I clean the build folder and re-attempt the build but it always throws the same error...I don't know if I've done everything correctly to create for iOS release anyway since there is no documentation...

Comment: is it possible for you to send screenshot of error with whats written before error

Comment: @Saloni Parikh Ok I pasted the whole error into my question.

Comment: try this
1)Opened XCode and pressed cmd + 1
2)Clicked on my project in the left panel, my target in the middle panel
3)Clicked on "Build Settings"
4)In the "Linking" section, under the "Dead Code Stripping" section, changed the setting for "Release" from "Yes" to "No"

or try this
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2685#issuecomment-142137371

Comment: @Saloni Parikh Lol I literally just found that myself from my old notes. React Native is still such a mess I see, with no docs and loads of dirty fixes and workarounds just to get a default project to work. Thanks for your help anyway.